# Filtering a view with multiple 'and' & 'or'

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, view

I have couple of columns I want to filter on **1)**Request Type and **2)**Status

Request Type has 7 possible options of which I only want to return values when:
A) [Request type] = "Ing Variance" or "Ing Substitution" or "SLE - Ing" ....
   after I get these results I want to filter further using the [Status] field/column...
B) [Status] = 'Declined' or [Status] = 'Complete'

In the end I want to show all records who have any of the three request types which have a status of declined or complete.

I'm finding this difficult to accomplish. Can you help?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to manually update your views `ViewQuery` property to make sure the conditions are grouped correctly.

Prepare your CAML query, then update your view to use this query. Example here using [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
$newview = @"
<Where>
    <And>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Request_x0020_Type" />
                <Value Type="Text">Ing Variance</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Request_x0020_Type" />
                <Value Type="Text">Ing Substitution</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Request_x0020_Type" />
                <Value Type="Text">SLE - Ing</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
        <Or>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Status" />
                <Value Type="Text">Declined</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Status" />
                <Value Type="Text">Complete</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>
"@
```

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite
$view = Get-PnPView -List "ListName" -Identity "ViewName" -Includes ViewQuery
$view.ViewQuery = $newview
$view.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: Thanks Rune - let me give this a shot and get back with my update...